# Issue with Leaderboard class

Tags: java, android, leaderboard

I made a game where the user must collect as many stars as  they can before getting hit by an obstacle. Every star they collect they get 1 point. When they day and if they get a Highscore they will be brought to the leader board screen where they can fill in their name. And if they die but don't get a highscore they will just be brought to the GameOver screen.

But, the issue I'm having is a weird one and I'm going to try to explain it as best as I can . So basically, the first time I start the game up and play through the game, when I die I go straight to the leader board screen regardless if it's a high score or not. But if I "play again" and I die and don't get a high score it works fine to where i'll just be brought to the Game over screen. And no matter how many times I "Play Again" the app works fine.
But, if I close the app and start it up again the very first time I play through the game it will bring me to the leader board screen regardless of the score. I'm wondering if anybody has and suggestions to why this might be happening?

I hope I explained that clearly I know it's an odd bug to have. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

My code:

**Game Engine Class:**

```
if (lives == 0 ) {
    GameActivity.end(score);
}

if (lives == 0 && score > Leaderboard.newScoreTB) {
    GameActivity.endd();
}
```

**Game Activity Class:**

```
static void end(int score) {
    Context context = AppConstants.gameActivityContext;
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, GameOver.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    AppConstants.score = score;
    context.startActivity(intent);
    ((Activity) context).finish();
}

static void endd() {
    Context context = AppConstants.gameActivityContext;
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Leaderboard.class);
    intent.putExtra("score", AppConstants.score);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    ((Activity) context).finish();
}
```

**Leaderboard class:**

```
 score = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("score");
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref",0);
        int scoreSP = pref.getInt("scoreSP",0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

        int scoreSB = pref.getInt("scoreSB",0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editorr = pref.edit();

        int scoreTB = pref.getInt("scoreTB",0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editorrr = pref.edit();
```

Comment: From the problem, it is clear that you are making some logical erro but with the provided code snippet is not enough to get it. I would suggest you to debug the code and check the value your are getting for lives, score and Leaderboard.newScoreTB. By doing this you will get to know why it is happening. Further your two if condition alway will satisfy if lives is 0 which may create a logical error in long term. So better to use if-else-if and keep the bottom if at top.

Comment: What is the value for `Leaderboard.newScoreTB`?

Comment: @BilalNaeem the value is 0

Comment: Ok so my guess is, the first time the user plays the game, the value for `Leaderboard.newScoreTB` is 0. The user dies with some score (greater than 0). The first condition executes, taking him to the GameOver screen after which the second condition executes which takes him to the Leaderboard screen. Now the user is on the Leaderboard screen. Just to confirm if this is the case, play a game and die without making any score (0 score) and check where you go (GameOver or Leaderboard). Also, for future plays, maybe you update the value of `Leaderboard.newScoreTB` somewhere which fixes the problem.

Comment: @BilalNaeem So I just tested that there. When I die and with a score of 0 it takes me to the GameOver screen. I closed the app and did it again but this time got a score of 1 and it took me to the Leadboard screen. My 3 highscores at  the moment are 5,4 and 3.

Comment: Just test one more thing, the first time you start playing, do you initialize the value of `Leaderboard.newScoreTB` or is it 0?

Comment: @BilalNaeem it's just 0

Comment: So this is where the problem lies. Before starting to play, you need to fetch the highest score that you have and set `Leaderboard.newScoreTB` to be that value.

Comment: @BilalNaeem Thanks for your help! I'll give it a shot.